# Running Perl from an Azure Web App

Tags: perl, azure

I am trying to run Perl from an Azure Web App using Fast CGI. I have set up PHP and it works ok, but can't get Perl working. To run Perl I have installed Strawberry Perl (I have tried both 32-bit and 64-bit, portable versions)

I have added a handler for *.pl as follows

```
d:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\perl\bin\perl.exe
```

I have a simple Perl program test.pl as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Hello, World!\n";
```

It runs from the Console if I type the following command (from the D:\home\site\wwwroot folder) so Perl is working ok.

```
> bin\perl\bin\perl.exe test.pl
```

If I view it using http

```
 http://mywebapppath/test.pl
```

I get a 500 error

If I look at the logs at get the following:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

d:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\perl\bin\perl.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly
```

I have run out of ideas what to try next. Any suggestions?

Comment: That is not a fastcgi script. Where and how have you added what handler exactly?

Comment: I clicked on settings for the Web app and added one in the handlers section. Like I say the test.pl runs from the console.

Comment: you still have to use a fastcgi script to have it handled by FastCGI, l would suggest taking a simple example script and trying that. Have a look at http://search.cpan.org/~skimo/FCGI-0.67/FCGI.PL

Comment: What I am trying do do is run my Perl scripts. My test.pl script is being handled by perl.exe, I tried that script you mentioned and gave it a .pl extension and got the same error, On my local PC have got my test.pl file to run in IIS by adding a Script Map hanlder in IIS that opens .pl files. The handlers for web apps do not seem to be quite equivalent though,

Comment: Aside from the fact that it might expect a .fcgi ending, not .pl for fastcgi, I am afraid I cannot really help you there, no experiences with Azure and few with windows+perl, sorry. I only noticed the FastCGI in your text and thought it might help. fastcgi may not make much sense anyway depending on what you want to do ( probably not printing Hello World ).

Comment: I managed to figure it out see my own answer which I will post if you are interested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to figure it out and it is quite obscure so I hope it helps if you have a similar problem.

Strawberry Perl (which goes in the bin folder so it can't be run from the outside) comes with a cpan.bat file and you need to install the Fast Cgi module from a Console in Azure using this batch file.

```
bin\perl\bin\cpan.bat -i /FCGI::IIS/
```

The second thing is to add an argument for the .pl handler in your web app.

```
-MFCGI::IIS=do
```

That's all you need to do. Just restart the server and Perl works from my test.pl page!

Comment: For future readers: Note that your .pl script must include a content type declaration (e.g. `print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n";`). Otherwise an error is thrown, which shows up in the logs as "The data is invalid").