# Running pearl scripts from Azure Logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

We have some pearl and powershell scripts running as scheduled jobs on windows server and writing to csv and text files. We are planning to move away from on-prem server to the cloud. What are the best options to run them?

Can they be scheduled to run within logic app?

Answer (score 0):

We can use schedule of logic app but currently we can't run powershell directly in logic app. So I suggest you to use Azure function. You can create a powershell function by following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-powershell). And when you do the step "**Select a template for your project's first function: Choose HTTP trigger**" of the document, you can choose **Timer trigger** instead.

[image]

After choose timer trigger, you can schedule the job with a cron expression. When you complete the powershell function code, you can [deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-powershell#publish-the-project-to-azure) it to azure.

Comment: @NethiSwapna Currently neither of azure function nor logic app support perl script. If you want to run perl scripts, you can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32308424/running-perl-from-an-azure-web-app).